# How to evaluate shell output during the run and make condition based on that?

Tags: linux, shell, docker

I am running a command `docker kill $(docker ps -aq)` using Jenkins but that fails since if there is no docker container running - output of `$(docker ps -aq)` will be 0 which will fail `docker kill` command and jenkins job will fail.

How to prevent that?

Was thinking something like:

```
if ( $(docker ps -aq) > 0)
then docker kill $(docker ps -aq)
fi
```

but syntax seems like is not working.

What is a good approach here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to use **xargs**(1) to translate the stdout from `docker ps` into command-line arguments to `docker kill`.  If there aren’t any arguments, it won’t run the command; if there are more arguments than fit on a single command line, it will run it multiple times.

```
docker ps -aq | xargs docker kill
```

Comment: This will throw an error if there are no containers.

Comment: _tries it_ This works correctly for me and doesn’t print an error, even if `docker ps -a` is empty.

Comment: On bash 4.4, fails with `docker kill requies at least one argument`

Answer (score 0):

It should work on Linux system:

```
if [[ $(docker ps -aq) -gt 0 ]]; then
    docker kill $(docker ps -aq)
else
    echo "There is no docker container running"
fi
```

Or you can change the `-gt` to `!=`.